# Service Console - Expendable/retractable list view of ALL emails of a contact, accessible from a case

Tags: related-list, service-cloud-console, console

Our support agents need an expendable/retractable list view of ALL emails from/to a contact, accessible easily from a case in the Service Console.

In a case, we can click on "All Emails", and we get a nice expendable/retractable emails list view, but it display only the emails related to that case.

We are searching for a similar feature listing ALL the emails from/to a contacts.

Ideally, i think the link should appear as my the screenshot below in red, and the results at the same place than the Results when you click on "All Emails"
[image]

I didnt find how to do it:-(
Thanks in advance for your help.